# Delete products from MySQL table when updating shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

// Removing products from shopping cart:

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
        foreach ($_SESSION['shop'] as $keys => $value) {
            if ($value['product_id'] == $_GET['id']) {
                unset($_SESSION['shop'][$keys]);
                if (empty($_SESSION['shop'])) {

                    // Removing products from database:

                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM basket WHERE product_id = $id";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

How do I remove a product from the table called 'basket'? With the above code I can only remove one product from the shopping cart if there actually is only one product. I guess I need to iterate over the ids of products, have been trying to use foreach loop to no avail:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
foreach($_GET['id'] as $id) {
$sql = "DELETE FROM basket WHERE product_id = $id";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Comment: This lacks proper information about what you are doing in multiple places. We don’t know what your data model is (identifying records to delete in a `basket` table based on product ID only seems weird - are you _not_ storing individual baskets for each user?), we don’t know what exactly you passed for the `id` parameter to begin with. And what exactly you have stored in your session at that point, we also don’t know.

Comment: Please expand on "to no avail" - in isolation, if `product_id` is your unique row identifier, then your second code should remove every row where the condition matches. What happens in your `basket` table when two users (or two hundred users) have things in their basket? Is there some way to identify which user this basket is for? If so, that would need to be in the query too, and if not, won't this be a problem?

Comment: Also this code may be vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, guys. I really appreciate them. I decided to start my project again and learn about shopping carts with the help of "Effortless e-Commerce (second edition)" by Larry Ullman.